# Elastic search partial updates without scripting

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do partial updates to a document, without using dynamic scripting using the REST API? The requests have to go over http/https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use the [`doc` parameter of the `_update` endpoint to partially update a document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document).

```
$ curl -XPUT host:9200/my-index/my-type/my-id -d '{
  "my_field" : "This is the original value",
  "other_field" : "This field won't be touched by the update"
}'

$ curl -XPOST host:9200/my-index/my-type/my-id/_update -d '{
  "doc" : {
    "my_field" : "changeme"
  }
}'
```

Note: This does a simple field-level replacement. Do not expect any type of concatenation to occur (for strings or arrays). For that type of behavior, scripts are required (or a two-step request where you fetch, then modify).